# Drawing a simple line with Tradingview's Pine at the right Y location

Tags: pine-script

In copying the sample and modifying I managed to get a line at the last candle with:

```
var line1 = line.new(x1=0, y1=low, x2=bar_index, y2=high, extend=extend.right)
line.set_x2(line1, 0)
line.set_xloc(line1, time, time, xloc.bar_time)
```

however right now the line goes from the top to the bottom of the chart. What I would like is to put the line at a particular height. For example, if the top of the candle is $10 I might want to put the line at the $11 height. However, when I change `y2` to $11 that's not where the line goes up to.

Also, once I get the height issue sorted I'm obviously going only have a dot so I'm going to want to make the line horizontal. It would be nice to be able to make it say, 1 or 2 or 3 candle widths so help with that as well would be appreciated.

Finally, something I don't understand that I'm hoping someone can enlighten me on which is since the x1 and x2 are set in the initial line why are two more lines setting x necessary?

Sorry for so many questions on just 3 lines of code, I've just started with Pine.

Answer (score 0):

This is coming down to being new and not initially understanding the interplay between x,y and the xloc functions. Also, I can get the y position I want if I set y with a hard coded number but these numbers are intrinsically of type series, hence the interplay between the three functions.

Answer (score 0):

This will draw a line starting on the last `low` and will extend for `n` bars.
You can edit this `n` bars by changing the input in the settings of this script.

```
//@version=4
study(title="Line", shorttitle="Li", overlay=true)

i_bars_to_extend = input(10, "Number of bars to extend line", input.integer)

var line    line1       = line.new(na, na, na, na, xloc.bar_time)
var int     bar_length  = na

f_move_line(_line, _x, _y) =>
    line.set_xy1(_line, _x, _y)
    line.set_xy2(_line, _x + i_bars_to_extend * bar_length, _y)

bar_length := int(min(change(time),change(time)[1]))

if barstate.islast
    f_move_line(line1, time, low)
```